# Trigger autocommand on error?

Tags: autocmd

Is there an autocommand that is triggered when an error occurs (a Vim error of the type E###)? A try/catch block isn't enough because I need it at a more global level.

Comment: It might be helpful if you can tell why you need it at global level.

Comment: Because it's for a plugin that works in a sub-mode, and if there's an error I'd like to quit the whole mode, not just a function.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't help, don't have enough experience with sub-mode. Hope your comment will help others to help you.

Comment: I provided a answer to the question. But from your comment, I assume that you should ask a different  question about plugins, sub-modes and error handling.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not really possible. It has been requested a couple of times ([here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/EbTWqBl2rdw/vT4fTaGFnMoJ), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/XzhNNjbtfow/u6BWsne4CwAJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/3_Mn38Jk3N0/W3TQ0g1WDQAJ) and even a [patch](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-mq-patches/blob/master/error_aucmd) has been proposed).

But Bram disregarded this so it has never been merged.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably check `v:errmsg` on `CursorMoved`, it could work for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such autocommand event.

You might simulate something with custom autocmd events. Like:

```
autocmd User MyErrorEvent  call MyErrorHandler()
```

and somewhere in the code you could trigger that autocmd with

```
doautocmd User MyErrorEvent
```

Comment: Thanks. The closest I could find for now is comparing `v:errmsg` to an older value, so I could put that in autocommand such as CursorMoved.

Comment: @mg979 If you found a solution to your problem, you could post an answer and mark it as accepted: that could be useful for future readers. :)